# Android Syntax Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, syntax-error

I get the following error messages when I run the app:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement    HelloWorldActivity.java > /HelloWorld/src/com/HelloWorld/test   line 55 Java Problem

Here is my code:

```
       toggleButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
            if (toggleButton1.isChecked()){
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource("http://audioplayer.wunderground.com/sunsetlakesFL/Melbourne.mp3.m3u");
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    error.setText(e.getMessage());
                    error.show();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    error.setText(e.getMessage());
                    error.show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    error.setText(e.getMessage());
                    error.show();
                }
            }
            else {
                mp.stop();
            }               
        }
  } //line 55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the closing parenthesis and semicolon of *setOnClickListener*.  This:

```
      }
  } //line 55
```

Should be this:

```
      }
  }); //line 55
```